# Adding .jar files to Matlab

Tags: matlab, jar

Bio-Formats is a pretty common toolbox used in MATLAB, and I want to use it to directly work with .nd2 files. As the website instructs (https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/5.8.2/users/matlab/index.html), I downloaded and unzipped the folder. I then added the .m files to my Matlab path, including the .jar file 'bioformats_package.jar'. However, I can't use any of the functions due to this error:

```
Error using bfopen (line 100)
Missing Bio-Formats library. Either add bioformats_package.jar to the static Java 
path or add it to the Matlab path.
```

I tried a few things, eg adding 'bioformats_package.jar' to the static Java path. I am inexperienced when it comes to working with libraries etc, so I may be missing something simple.

For reference, all of my work/files are in '\Users\user_name\Documents\MATLAB\Image Analysis'

I pasted all of the files from the Bio-Formats website directly in this 'Image Analysis' folder, along with the rest of my .m files. Yet I can't use Bio-Formats.

Comment: Please add your MATLAB version, your Bioformats version, and your OS (make and version). These things might be relevant. Bioformats should be adding the JAR file to the Java path for you, I don’t think there is anything else you need to do.

Comment: Also, I suggest you leave those files in their own folder, and add that folder to your MATLAB path using `addpath`. It’s safer and easier to upgrade later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need download bfmatlab.zip and extract it, then move \bfmatlab\bfmatlab to your current MATLAB path, or add the bfmatlab folder itself to MATALB path. In your case, moving all files under \bfmatlab\bfmatlab to '\Users\user_name\Documents\MATLAB\Image Analysis' will work fine.

When bfopen is called, internal bfCheckJavaPath function will add bioformats_package.jar to MATLAB's dynamic Java path, so you don't need to add this jar to Java path by yourself.

Comment: I have already done that, but I just deleted everything and re-downloaded bfmatlab. I moved the folder into 'Image Analysis'. Then, in Matlab, I added the folder to the path. All of the files were successfully added, including 'bioformats_package.jar'. However, none of folders inside 'bioformats_package.jar' itself are on the path, and I am not given the option to add them. This is where I'm stuck

Comment: Went back and checked my 'classpath.txt'
Basically, I confused Matlab by adding to the static and dynamic Java classes in silly ways. Thanks for the help!